# Threads are not able to acquire locks even though no one else is using them

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking

I am trying to write a code that is using threads in order to find files that contain a specific string in their name.

My code works most of the times. in some specific cases, threads are not able to acquire locks for some reason.

I tried debugging really hard (using prints, as you can see in the code) but I couldn't find the problem.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

void* threadFunction(void* searchTerm);
bool scanDirName(char * path, char * searchTerm);
int numOfThreads;
pthread_mutex_t qlock;
pthread_cond_t cond;
int count;
int matchingFiles;

struct Node {
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

// Two global variables to store an address of front and rear nodes.
    struct Node* front = NULL;
    struct Node* rear = NULL;

// To Enqueue an integer
void Enqueue(char* x) {
/*    printf("\nhere\n");*/
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data =x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = temp;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;

}

// To Dequeue an integer.
char* Dequeue() {
    struct Node* temp = front;
    if(front == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char* data;
    data = front->data;
    if(front == rear) {
        front = rear = NULL;

    }
    else {
        front = front->next;
    }
//    printf("\nfreeing %p, %s\n", temp, temp->data);
    free(temp);
    return data;
}

void* threadFunction(void* st) {
    bool isFinished;
    isFinished = false;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);
    while (true) {
        char *filepath;
        char *searchTerm;
        searchTerm = (char *) st;

        filepath = Dequeue();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
        if (filepath == NULL) {
            printf("%ld waiting for lock \n",(long) pthread_self());
            pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);
            count++;
            if (isFinished) {
                printf("%ld waking u up, we found %d items!\n",(long) pthread_self(), matchingFiles);
                pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
                if (count == numOfThreads) {
                    printf("Thread exited: %ld\n", (long) pthread_self());
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
                    pthread_exit((void*)0);
                }
            }
            isFinished = false;

            printf("%ld going to sleep\n",(long) pthread_self());
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &qlock);
            printf("%ld Woke up, try to compare %d == %d\n",(long) pthread_self(), count, numOfThreads);
            if (count == numOfThreads) {
                printf("Thread exited: %ld\n", (long) pthread_self());
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
                pthread_exit((void*)1);
            }
            printf("%ld compare failed \n",(long) pthread_self());
            count--;

        }
        else {
            printf("%ld deq 1 item \n",(long) pthread_self());
            isFinished = scanDirName(filepath, searchTerm);
        }
    }



}

bool scanDirName(char * path, char * searchTerm){
    DIR * d = opendir(path); // open the path
    char* str3;

    if(d==NULL) return false; // if was not able return

;

    struct dirent * dir; // for the directory entries
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) // if we were able to read somehting from the directory
    {
        printf("%ld STARTED A ROUND!\n",(long) pthread_self());
        if(dir-> d_type == DT_DIR){ //
            if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 & strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0) // if it is a directory
            {
                str3 = malloc((1+strlen("/")+ strlen(path)+ strlen(dir->d_name))*sizeof(char));
                if (!str3){
                    return false;
                }

                strcpy(str3, path);
                strcat(str3, "/");
                strcat(str3, dir->d_name);
//                printf("\n---\n%s\n---\n",str3);
                printf("%ld waiting for lock in func \n",(long) pthread_self());
                pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);
                printf("%ld wake threads \n",(long) pthread_self());
                Enqueue(str3);
                pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
                printf("%ld enq \n",(long) pthread_self());
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
                printf("%ld locks gone \n",(long) pthread_self());

            }
        }
        else if(dir-> d_type == DT_REG){ //
            if(strstr(dir->d_name, searchTerm)){
                matchingFiles++;
                /*printf("%s/%s\n", path, dir->d_name);*/
            }
        }

        printf("%ld finished A ROUND!\n",(long) pthread_self());
    }
    printf("%ld finished scanning!\n",(long) pthread_self());
    fflush(stdout);
    closedir(d); // finally close the directory
    if (count == numOfThreads-1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    count = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&qlock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    matchingFiles = 0;

    if (argc != 4){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* rootSearchDir = argv[1];
    char* searchTerm = argv[2];
    int threadsNumber = atoi(argv[3]);

    pthread_t threadsCollection[threadsNumber];

    Enqueue(rootSearchDir);
    numOfThreads = threadsNumber;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<threadsNumber; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&threadsCollection[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void*)searchTerm)) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&qlock);
            return 1;

        }
    }

    int rc;

    for (i=0; i<threadsNumber; i++){
        rc = pthread_join((threadsCollection[i]), NULL);
        if(rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread, %d\n", rc);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&qlock);
            return 1;

        }
    }



}
```

I have attached all of the code (maybe it is important) but I suspect the problem is in scanDirName or threadFunction.

--- EDIT ---

I found the problem. I had a logical problem with the locks, fixed it.
Thanks all!

Comment: In the call to `pthread_cond_wait` right after `isFinished = false;` and before the `if (count == numOfThreads)`, what exactly is the thread waiting for? If it's waiting for a call to `Enqueue`, how do you know that hasn't already happened and you're waiting for something that has already taken place?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The thread is waiting until someone will send a signal\broadcast to this condition variable. I am doing this because I don't want to busy-wait and waste CPU time.

Comment: Debugging with gdb and `thr a a bt` might yield better results than printf.

Comment: @DarkSkylo You can't use condition variables that way. They're stateless, so you can't wait for them to change state. Sooner or later, this will bite you.

Answer (score 0):

1. if filepath = Dequeue() returns a non-null; then your next iteration of this loop will call Dequeue() without holding &qlock.  If you checked the return values, you would notice this.
2. scanDirName relies on count to set its return value; however it isn’t protected by qlock { see #1 }

If I read your code correctly, you are attempting to make a sort of dispatch mechanism, where names are emitted from scanDir() into a queue, and pulled from the queue, where a fresh scanDir() is spun up for each item.  The handling of count is an attempt to detect whether the Dequeue failed because there is nothing left to do, or everyone is busy doing scanDirs.

There is a bit easier of a mechanism:  use two queues.  Scandir dumps entries into say “NameQ”, and thread function pulls names out of NameQ, dumping them into WorkQ.  When a thread runs out of NameQ items, it looks into WorkQ for fresh ones to dispatch.  Then you just have to keep track of how many threads are in scanDir().   If both queues are empty, and number of threads in scanDir is zero, there is nothing more to do.   Your Basic logic ends up looking like this:

```
void* threadFunction(void* st) {
    static int nreader = 0;
    int ncount = 0, wcount = 0;
    char *searchTerm;
    searchTerm = (char *) st;
    Menter(&qlock);
    while (nreader || !(empty(&Names) && empty(&Work))) {
        char *filepath;
        filepath = Dequeue(&Names);
        if (filepath) {
            ncount++;
            Enqueue(&Work, filepath);
        } else if ((filepath = Dequeue(&Work)) != NULL) {
            wcount++;
            nreader++;
            Mexit(&qlock);
            scanDirName(filepath, searchTerm);
            Menter(&qlock);
            nreader--;
            cv_wake(&cond);
        } else {
            cv_wait(&cond, &qlock);
        }
    }
    Mexit(&qlock);
    printf("%p: %d, %d items\n", pthread_self(), ncount, wcount);
    return NULL;
}
```

Mexit, Menter are error checking covers for the posix funs, and a lot easier on the eyes than all that redundant typing...

```
static int menter(pthread_mutex_t *m, int line) {
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(m) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%p:%d  Mutex lock failed!\n", pthread_self(),line);
        abort();
    }
    DEBUG_LOCK("%d locked\n", line);
    return 0;
}
#define Menter(x) menter((x), __LINE__)
static int mexit(pthread_mutex_t *m, int line) {
    DEBUG_LOCK("%d unlocked\n", line);
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock(m) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%p:%d  Mutex unlock failed!\n", pthread_self(),line);
        abort();
    }
    return 0;
}
#define Mexit(x) mexit((x), __LINE__)
```